# Create datetime object with millisecod

Tags: python, datetime

I am printing a datetime object from a returned object of some function.

```
a = test_object.upload_time
print('datetime', a, type(a))
# datetime 2021-03-18 15:59:08.300000+00:00 <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

I want to create an equal datetime to `a`. Let this be `b`.

```
b = datetime.datetime(
        year=2021, month=3, day=18, 
        hour=15, minute=59, second=8, microsecond=3
        )
print('datetime', b, type(b))
# datetime 2021-03-18 15:59:08.000003 <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

`a`'s milli or micro? seconds is not the same with `b`. How can I declare `b` using `datetime` to equal `a`?

Comment: What was the problem with `b = a`?

Comment: `self.assertEqual(a, b)`, I am testing them, they are not equal

Comment: Yes of course not, because you are creating them differently. But, if you want to create a `b` that is identical to `a`, why did you not just use `b = a`?

Comment: because I guess that @Nikko is doing unit testing

Comment: Because I want to create b from datetime explicitly because I am unit testing. @dallonsi is right.

Comment: @Nikko, as suggested, first convert a and b in timestamp format (see the update in my answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 million of micro seconds is a second, so you have to specify 300 000 microseconds, like this:

```py
import datetime

b = datetime.datetime(
        year=2021, month=3, day=18,
        hour=15, minute=59, second=8, microsecond=300000
        )
print('datetime', b, type(b))
```

@Wimanicesir made the following suggestion: In your unit test, if you want to check that `a` equals `b`, convert first `a` and `b` to timestamps like this:

```py
timestamp_a = datetime.datetime.timestamp(a)
timestamp_b = datetime.datetime.timestamp(b)
assert timestamp_a == timestamp_b
```

UPDATE:
this `00+00` appears when you set a timezone:

```py
import datetime
import pytz

b = datetime.datetime(year=2021, month=3, day=18, hour=15, minute=59, second=8, microsecond=300000, tzinfo=pytz.utc)
print('datetime', b, type(b))
# datetime 2021-03-18 15:59:08.300000+00:00 <class 'datetime.datetime'>
```

Comment: How to add the `+00:00`? `self.assertEqual(a, b)`, They are not yet equal.

Comment: Convert the datetime to unix timestamp before checking if they are equal

Comment: Well it solves a==b, but what is `+00:00`. Is that a timezone?

Comment: Ok. I am now satisfied since it is equal and printed similarly. Thanks!

Comment: First of all, you *can* compare datetime objects (but note the difference between aware and naive datetime). Then, are you sure you want to compare equality for floating point numbers? And also note that Python has [zoneinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html) by now.